# Finding the total sum based a few criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working with the following excel workbook:
[Workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIGcv.png)

I wanted a feature where I can find the total number of doors that need fixing, but based on Brand and Model of the cars. For example in the workbook, there are 5 Honda Vios (Blue) that needs to fix 1 door, then 2 Honda Vios (Red) that needs to fix 2 doors. Therefore, is there any formulation (sumifs / countifs) that I can use so that I can easily find the total number of doors that need fixing?

Comment: So the result should be 9?

Comment: why not creating a pivot table ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I am not familiar with Pivot table yet, so I'm not aware of what it is capable of.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will update my answer with a pivot table

Comment: @Visitorss then you do some search before asking here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell G2 add this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:F2;"YES")*D2
```

And drag it down.
This will count the number of doors on this row.

Then create a new table with the unique items and add the following formula which will sum all blue Honda Vios doors.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=M2)*(B:B=N2)*(C:C=O2)*G:G)
```

[image]

If "ES" is included:

```
=(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ES",E2)),1,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ES",F2)),1,0))*D2
```

Regarding pivot table.
First make the table a official table by clickin on a cell in the table and go to insert -> table

[image]

Then again, click inside the table and go to insert -> Pivot table.
(To make it easier I added the pivot table on the same sheet)

Now set up the pivot as following:

[image]

When you add new items to your table, the pivot table must be refreshed.
Click on pivot table and go to Analyse -> refresh

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. The color filter wasn't necessary, only Brand and Model, so I just remove `(C:C=O)` right?

Comment: Correct! Or as Patrick said make a pivot table. Either way will work

Comment: Just another question, is it possible to use `COUNTIF` on partial of the string? For example, COUNT the total number of "ES" appear in the range. So, cells containing YES or BEST or TEST will be counted as well, as long as the string contain "ES"

Comment: Thanks for the guide. That helped me out so much.